# Golang Excelize: how to set cell value with row nmber and column number

Tags: excel, go, axis

I am trying to write a function that writes a string array to excel in Go, using Excelize.
My question: how to address a cell with row number and col number, instead of the "A1" type of syntax for the "axis" parameter ?

```
// Writes the header of the file:  
xlfile.SetCellValue("Sheet1", "A1", "1")

// Instead of "A1", I would like to use row number and col number as parameters
```

Comment: what do you mean column number? `1` instead of `A`?

Comment: If you mean coordinates, this should work: https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize#CoordinatesToCellName

Answer (score 3):

[CoordinatesToCellName](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/xuri/excelize/v2#CoordinatesToCellName) converts [X, Y] coordinates to alpha-numeric cell name or returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ascii code `(A = 65)`:

```golang
rowNumber := 1 // what you want (minimum is 1)
colNumber := 1 // what you want (minimum is 1)

xlfile.SetCellValue("Sheet1", string(rune(64+colNumber))+string(rowNumber), "1")
```